# How can the activity of ions be more than 1 if the activity of water is 1?

Tags: equilibrium, solvents

Now, I am quoting Chemlibretexts when they give the activity coefficient of $\ce{LiCl}$ to be $\pu{1.026}$ at the molality of $\pu{2.5 mol kg-1}$

For simplicity, assuming this is aqueous, I'll just convert the molality to concentration, since it shouldn't really affect it that much.

Given $y$ $\mathrm{=\frac{a}{[C]}}$
And here my question begins.

$\ce{LiCl}$ is a spectacularly soluble substance, $\pu{84.25g/100ml}$ or $\pu{19.8 molL-1}$, which indicates that at a concentration of about $\pu{2.5 molL-1}$ is nowhere close to saturation, and indeed, I do not believe there will be any repulsive effects between the water and the $\ce{Li+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions.

In aqueous solution, the activity of water is 1, because there is so much of it around that it cannot really affect direction of reaction by Le-Chatelier's principle.

Therefore, the equilibrium constant of a reaction even involving water in aqueous solution is written without water.

Activity is supposed to be a measure of effective concentration; i.e. the availability of a substance in a given volume.

So how is it that, $\ce{LiCl}$, can have an activity of $\pu{2.6}$ at a relatively low concentration of $\pu{2.5 molL-1}$, while water, which surrounds the entire reaction with roughly a concentration of $\pu{55 mol dm^-3}$ and is always in excess and available for reaction, can only achieve an activity of 1? Is there something special about a solute that allows it's activity to exceed 1?

This is because that $\ce{LiCl}$ having an activity above 1 somehow implies that $\ce{LiCl}$ is more available for reaction than water, which to me is bizarre.

I have seen other somewhat similar questions, but none of them touch on this paradox, or they only mention hydrophobic substances such as benzene where repulsion may be a cause.

Comment: Activity value depends on what activity is conventionally chosen for the compound as unit activity, by equation $\mu = \mu_0 + RT \ln{\frac{a}{a_0}}$. Activity coefficient of hydronium in concentrated HCl near 12 M is about 20, so hydronium activity is about 240. For water the activity is defined as 1 for pure water, for ions activity is equal to concentration as the limit value for infinitely diluted solution.

Comment: Hmm...it's still kind of odd to me. How is it that highly concentrated solutes can reach very high effective concentrations while much "concentrated" solvents are left with an activity of about 1? The way I see it, water doesn't affect equilibrium because changing it in any way does not affect the equilibrium position given that it is already so much in excess that it is always available for reaction. Should the same effect not apply to Hydronium at higher concentrations, lowering it's effective concentration to below that of water? In fact, what do conc/activity graphs look like?

Comment: You don't really compare the activities if different substances.

Comment: Still though, it seems very odd simply because the magnitude of the difference is a 240x magnitude in a situation where I would expect water to have the higher effective concentration, simply because it's concentration is 55.6 mol dm^-3 while that of hydronium is 12 mol dm^-3
Basically, I just fail to see how the effective concentration (in a way, availability for reaction) of a solute can exceed that for the solvent, given that the solvent is everywhere, especially by such a large magnitude.
I would expect the activity coefficient to decrease as concentration increases, like pH and activity

Comment: Activity can be considered as "effective concentration" just accidentally, if it is defined so for given compound state. Water activity = 1 has no relation to concentration.

Comment: Also the effective concentration is not linked to the spatial notion you have in mind. It goes the other way around,if I understand you correctly. In general the activity coefficient approaches its maximum with decreasing conc.

Comment: If it is not effective concentration, what exactly is activity and what makes the activity of a solute possibly much higher than a solvent? The wikipedia page mentions the idea of effective concentration.

Comment: Read the first comment few times more. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity

Comment: Aight. I understand what you mean to some extent, but I can't really formulate an explanation of all this.
Is there something fundamentally different between a solvent reacting and a solute reacting that leads to such wildly different values to come out? I think that is the core of my question.

Comment: The core point is that the unit activity levels are deliberately chosen, linked to well defined state and to the chemical potential chosen as the standard one. For solvent it is the pure solvent state, for ions it is infinite dilution state, ideally extrapolated to unit concentration, with activity numerically equal to concentration for c->0. Therefore, activities of different species are not directly comparable as concentrations are, because they are context dependent.

Comment: Related: [Activity Coefficients of Concentrated Salt Solutions: A Monte Carlo Investigation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10953-019-00905-y)

Comment: What makes you think that the activity of water remains constant?